# How do I draw an Oval on an HTML Canvas that comes out smoother than this one?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, smoothing

Here is a picture of the widget I made:

[image]

Here is the main function that calls all the primitive shapes:

```
function cylinder(ctx, w, h, fill_percent){
    y_origin = h;
    x_origin = 0;
    drawContainerBottom(ctx, x_origin, y_origin, w, h);
    drawContentBottom(ctx, x_origin, y_origin, w, h);
    drawContentFront(ctx, x_origin, y_origin, w, h, fill_percent);
    drawContentTop(ctx, x_origin, y_origin, w, h, fill_percent);
    drawContainerFront(ctx, x_origin, y_origin, w, h);
    drawContainerTop(ctx, x_origin, y_origin, w, h);
}
```

Here is the function to draw the top of the outer container, the main one that looks bad:

```
function drawContentTop(ctx, x, y, w, h, fill_percent){
    Contents_offset=5;
    w=w-2*Contents_offset;
    x=x+Contents_offset;
    h=h;
    y=y-h+Contents_offset+(h-w/4-2*Contents_offset)*(1-fill_percent);
    var i; 
    var xPos; 
    var yPos; 
    var twoPi = 2 * Math.PI;
    ctx.beginPath();

    //Top
    for (i = 0; i < twoPi; i += 0.001) {
        xPos = (x + w / 2) - (w / 2 * Math.cos(i));
        yPos = (y + w / 8) + (w / 8 * Math.sin(i));

        if (i === 0) {
            ctx.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
        } else {
            ctx.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
        }
    }

    ctx.fillStyle="rgba(0, 99, 188, .5)";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(0, 99, 188, 1)";
    ctx.stroke();
};
```

And here is how I call it:

```
<canvas name='pool_graphic' class='pool_graphic' width='125' height='125' style='padding:10px'></canvas><br />
<canvas name='pool_graphic' class='pool_graphic' width='125' height='125' style='padding:10px'></canvas><br />
<script>
    $("td canvas[name='pool_graphic']").each(function(){
        var ctx = this.getContext('2d');
        var padding = this.style.padding.replace(/[^0-9]+/, '');
        var w=this.width
        var h=this.height;
        var fill_percent=1;
        cylinder(ctx, w, h, fill_percent);

    });
</script>
```

Firstly, why is it only the top and bottom of the outside container that looks bad when I am using the same manual type loop in all cases? Secondly, how do I fix the jaggedness?

EDIT: Just kept tweeking using the techniques discussed and here is what I got

[image]

Comment: When you say the top and the bottom look bad, what specifically are you referring to? Are you talking about the appearance of the outline when it is shown with black on one side? (I.e the top and bottom 25 pixels of the image you've shown.) Dont forget, anti-aliasing involves blending colours of pixels. When you have 4 pixels to blend from black to white (for instance), each of the 4 pixels will look more different to it's neighbour than if you were blending white to light-grey. Drawing with a higher resolution can make these blended regions represent a smaller proportion of the image.

Comment: Some sort of smoothing or anti aliasing filter may do the trick, but this is java script not Photoshop so I don't know how. The problem is that it looks visibly digitized on the highest and lowest lines only, everything else is nice and smooth. The issue is MOST pronounced at the tippy top and bottom where the oval almost looks 100% flat.

Comment: You can make use of anti-aliasing (as your picture already does) using the canvas element. If you wish to display the image at 128x128, you may instead generate the image with a canvas of 256x256. If this canvas with 65536 pixels (256x256) is then displayed at 128x128, the browser will be responsible for creating a 128x128 representation of these 256x256 pixels. So `<canvas width=256 height=256 style='width:128px; height:128px id='someId'></canvas>` will do the trick, (more data pixels than display pixels) just remember to base drawing calcs on a size of 256 instead of the 128 it's shown at.

Comment: I've tried this solution with various configurations. I think that since the stroke is only 1px, the down sampling required in this solution actually makes the situation worse.... i.e. the more I vary the ratio, the more jaggedness I see everywhere, not just the top. I'm thinking the best solution might be to replace the manual circle functions with a javascript ellipse function that likely would take care of this issue and may actually be faster. What do you think and how would I convert the above to use that function?

Comment: Hmmm. I'd just be inclined to make the line thinner at first, since that'll be the quicker option. (canvas lines dont have to be integral widths, you can indeed have a line that's 0.5px thick, it will be anti-alliased for you) It will still be shown as at least 1px thick, but the colour will show differently. Failing that, I'd certainly look into using the in-built curve functions. I'd probably try using bezier curves. Here's a quick starter: http://www.williammalone.com/briefs/how-to-draw-ellipse-html5-canvas/

Comment: I actually increased line thickness and it helps. When I do your trick with 1px stroke, sometimes the stroke is 1px, sometimes its 0px depending how it sampled. The situation is worse with .5px linestroke, everything is very jagged with that. 2px stroke helps the most so far, but not good enough. google images 'cylinder gauge javascript'... why do those work so well? I'm a liitle scared to jump into bezier.. how do I convert my code so it still functions... the content fill percentage function equations where very very complicated to write, and I'm scared to touch em.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88819/discussion-between-enhzflep-and-user2550940).

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, Curves are always prone to jaggies.

Perhaps experiment with scaling the Y of a circle?

[image]

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);

oval(150,150,75,.38);

function oval(cx,cy,radius,percentY){
  // draw thrice with slight offset to fill a few jaggies
  drawOval(cx,cy,radius,percentY);
  drawOval(cx,cy+0.50,radius,percentY);
  drawOval(cx+0.50,cy+0.75,radius,percentY);
}

function drawOval(cx,cy,radius,percentY){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(cx,cy);
  ctx.scale(1,percentY);
  ctx.arc(0,0,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.strokeStyle='gainsboro';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Interesting, your using the arc function and still have the issue. And based on your comment this is a common problem, likely to all of computer graphics except super advanced software like photoshop. It seems to be something you really got to play with, to 'giggle', depending on a number of factors like canvas size oval height, and background color. I found increasing the stroke width helps a good bit, but I bet someone out there has a better solution. Maybe drawing a dark arc above the light one, i.e. it might blend to the background instead of transparent better.

Comment: Assuming you have the design freedom, increasing the line width does help. Also applying the stroke several times helps (see the code in my answer).

Comment: yeah, doing multiple strokes kinda helps... almost same as increasing the line width. The only real issue it that it looks like the tippy top and bottom are flat on mine, but I'm probably the only one to notice. I found that Photoshops oval shape exhibited the same issues, even illustrator exhibited the issue really badly at certain zooms. So this is obviously common to all computer graphics. It can only be compensated for and doing that dynamically based on different size, background colors, resolution, etc, isn't practal... but you all have given me the tools I need to minimize it I think.